# HTML/Javascript Homework

Tags: javascript, html

-Make the title of this page: "(Your Name)'s Username Suggestion App".
-Write a button to the screen that the user should click to start the app.
-Prompt the user for three items: Their first name, their last name, and their favorite number. For example, I might respond with "George", "Washington", and "42".
-Convert the two names to lowercase. Get the first letter of the first name. --Create a string comprised of this: last name + first character of first name + favorite number. For example, George Washington's suggested username would be "washingtong42".

I am stuck on this problem. I do not know if I am using the .toLowerCase() method or the charAt() method correctly in order to get a username that resembles anything like the example he provided: washingtong42. And I have no idea how to combine the information together. Please help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ellis Jordan's Username App</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet"
        type = "text/css"
        href = "style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function userPrompt()
    {
        var first = prompt("What is your first name?");
        document.getElementById('firstname').innerHTML = first;

        var letter = first.charAt(0);
        document.getElementById('firstletter').innerHTML = letter;
        letter = letter.toLowerCase();

        var last = prompt("What is your last name?");
        document.getElementById('lastname').innerHTML = last;
        last = last.toLowerCase();

        var number = prompt("What is your favorite number?");
        document.getElementById('favnumber').innerHTML = number;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Ellis Jordan's Username App</h1>
        </header>
            <input type="button" onclick="userPrompt()"value="Enter your user information" />
            <p>Your first name is <span id="lastname" + "firstletter" + "favnumber">(incomplete information)</span>&nbsp;.</p>
        <footer>
            <p id="copyright"><b>&copy; 2019 Ellis Jordan</b></p>           
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

With how I currently have the code if I click on the button and "Enter my user information" it prompts me for my first name and after I push ok it does not prompt for the last name or favorite number and just ends.

Comment: You don't have any elements with id values `firstname` etc. to write the values into...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `<span id="lastname" + "firstletter" + "favnumber">` is not valid. And, you don't have any elements with `id="firstname"`, `id="firstletter"`, etc. So I have commented out the lines referring to these elemnents in your JS code. If you want to print firstname, lastname, etc. too, then simply add elements with the respective `id`(s). I have added a `span` having `id="result"` which would contain the final result:

```
<p>Suggested Username: <span id="result">(incomplete information)</span>&nbsp;.</p>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function userPrompt()
{
    var first = prompt("What is your first name?");
    //document.getElementById('firstname').innerHTML = first;

    var letter = first.charAt(0);
    //document.getElementById('firstletter').innerHTML = letter;
    letter = letter.toLowerCase();

    var last = prompt("What is your last name?");
    //document.getElementById('lastname').innerHTML = last;
    last = last.toLowerCase();

    var number = prompt("What is your favorite number?");
    //document.getElementById('favnumber').innerHTML = number;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = last+letter+number;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with bellow code, I hope it help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Thimble Sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Hannah Jones' Username Suggestion App</h1>
    </header>
    <input type="button" onclick="userPrompt()" value="Enter your user information" />
    <p>output: <span id="userInfo">(incomplete information)</span>&nbsp;.</p>
    <footer>
      <p id="copyright"><b>&copy; 2019 Hannah Jones</b></p>           
    </footer>
    <script>
      function userPrompt()
      {
        var firstName = prompt("What is your first name?");
        var firstName_firstLetter = firstName.charAt(0).toLowerCase();

        var lastName = prompt("What is your last name?");
        lastName = lastName.toLowerCase();

        var number = prompt("What is your favorite number?");
        document.getElementById('userInfo').innerHTML = lastName+firstName_firstLetter+number;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```